# Benefits of initializing properties in constructor?

Tags: c#

I noticed some places in our code base that initialize properties in the constructor like this:

```
public MyObject()
{
    this.Id = Guid.Empty;
    this.GroupId = Guid.Empty;
    this.Name = string.Empty;
    this.URL = string.Empty;
    this.Accounts= new List<Account>();
}

public Guid Id { get; set; }  
public Guid GroupId { get; set; }  
public string Name { get; set; }  
public string URL { get; set; }  
public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
```

And then some places just initialize constructors with the same types of properties like this:

```
public MyObject()
{
    this.Accounts= new List<Accounts>();
}
public Guid Id { get; set; }  
public Guid GroupId { get; set; }  
public string Name { get; set; }  
public string URL { get; set; }  
public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
```

and then just assign values to the properties whenever needed. Is there any benefit/reason to initialize properties like this in the constructor? I can see why you'd want to initialize objects like the List, but why the strings and Guids?

Comment: What is your definition of a "Benefit"?

Comment: Speculation: perhaps a developer that at the time was not familiar with C# default initialization did this. Perhaps it a developer added these during a debugging session, where they attempted using different values, and left it there, forgotten. The only slight benefit I find is that shows intend, that is, it shows that these are the desired default values and not that they forgot to put some in place. By the way, the strings would default to null, not to String.Empty, so those are doing something.

Comment: Someone probably tries to avoid NullReferenceExceptions by initializing string properties with `string.Empty`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to realize the fact that in both version of constructor it's actually doing the same thing .. that's your constructor is performing some sort of default initialization. For value type even if you don't initialize explicitly it will be `default(valuetype)` but for reference type it will be `null`. Also, it's always better to return a empty collection to your caller than returning null and thus your constructor performing a default initialization saying `this.Accounts= new List<Accounts>();`

I don't see any specific benefit of one version over the other but if you employ Microsoft `StyleCop` then it may throw some warning for the second version (guessing).

Comment: Absolutely, I understand why it's better to return initialize objects. But is there any reason to initialize these properties to empty vs just leaving them null until they are initialized when they need to be assigned to?

Comment: @jlee, one reason is best practice which also known as `NULL Object Pattern` and other is what if caller missed to perform null check before accessing properties ... end up in nullref exception

Answer (score 1):

There is no benefit in the example you show, since you are assigning the default values to those properties. The compiler will have done this for you regardless.

There is also no real benefit to assign a **public** property in the constructor other than to give an indication of what **you** think is a good default value for this property.

The real value of the constructor is to assign values to the **private** state of the object. So this is not at all reflected in the example you show.

Comment: `string.Empty` is not the default value!